# C# Regex why 2 \\ needed in the following example?

Tags: c#

This is from an example from MS. I don't understand why in Mr.\.? etc. there are 2 escape chars in C#, in a regex-tester one has to write only Mr.?, so it must be C# specific.

```
public static void Main()
{
   string pattern = "(Mr\\.? |Mrs\\.? |Miss |Ms\\.? )";
   string[] names = { "Mr. Henry Hunt", "Ms. Sara Samuels", 
                      "Abraham Adams", "Ms. Nicole Norris" };
   foreach (string name in names)
      Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(name, pattern, String.Empty));
}
```

Comment: point is an special Char in regex, it must be scaped and for that is the backslash...

Comment: I have pasted in the Code, but the important part is wrong, it should read Mr\\.? |Mrs\\.? | ...

Comment: A little neater and saves your slashes [{1}M][{1}r,s,i][{1}s,.][s]?[.]?   http://regexr.com/

Comment: you can use @ also

Answer (score 2):

There are two things going on here. In c# there are certain chars in strings which require an escape sequence:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

> A character that follows a backslash character () in a regular-string-literal-character must be one of the following characters: ', ", \, 0, a, b, f, n, r, t, u, U, x, v. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

So the first backslash is to make the string valid - it has nothing to do with Regex's.

The second thing going on is that the period means "match any character" in the Regex so to match an *actual period* it must be escaped with a single slash.

The single slash requires a second slash simply to make the string literal valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `\` to escape the `.` character and you have to use 2 `\` so that the first `\` is escaped also.

```
Mr.   - means match Mr[anything] 
Mr\.  - means match Mr\[anything]
Mr\\. - means match Mr.
```

I hope this is understandable.

Comment: Why would you want to escape the escape character.. I'm not sure about this explanation

Comment: I have never read that one has to escape the escape character! For me, \\ means the plain Character \ not in the meaning as an escape.

Comment: @NewbieEK The `.` is not a special character in a normal string only in regex so the second `\` is there so that the first one is escaped

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by looking up the properties of a regular string - as oposed to a verbatim string - in C#. Inside a string "  " a \ can only be used in combination with certain characters, for example one can use \t oder \n, but . is not allowed. So to get the output (Mr. one has to write "(Mr\., so that the first \ escapes the second .